# difference between function and &function

Tags: php

```
function fun1();
function &fun1();
```

What is the difference  between these??

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php

Comment: sorry for the dupe.  I wasn't sure if there was a difference when being used through a function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you put an ampersand before your function name, the function will return a reference to a variable instead of the value.

> Returning by reference is useful when you want to use a function to
>   find to which variable a reference should be bound. Do not use
>   return-by-reference to increase performance. The engine will
>   automatically optimize this on its own. Only return references when
>   you have a valid technical reason to do so.

From the [PHP Manual on Returning References](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php).

Comment: so if I return by reference (say $var = fun(123) ) does that mean when I change $var, then it actually changes the variable inside the function (the variable inside fun)?

Comment: The reference will point to the same memory address. When you modify the reference, you also modify the original object.

Comment: This site may help, as well: http://www.elated.com/articles/php-references/

Answer (score 6):

The difference is how the return value is returned: Without `&` the return value is returned by value and [with `&` the return value is returned by reference](http://php.net/language.references.return).

The latter implies that you need to use a variable in the `return` statement as you can only reference variables.